# I keep getting a "cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object" in python and cannot understand why

Tags: python

this is the full code I've been working on.

```
import random
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

def gauss_test(sigma):
    phi = random.uniform(0.0, 2.0 * math.pi)
    Upsilon = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    Psi = - math.log(Upsilon)
    r = sigma * math.sqrt(2.0 * Psi)
    x = r * math.cos(phi)
    y = r * math.sin(phi)
    return [x, y]

N = 4
radius = 0.15
n_runs = 100000
kb = 1
T = 300
m = 6.626 * 1e-21
constant_value = np.sqrt((kb * T) / m) 

data_x = []
data_y = []

for sample in range(n_runs):
    v = gauss_test(constant_value)
    data_x += [v[0]]
    data_y += [v[1]]

data3 = [ly/ n_runs for lx, ly in data_y]
data4 = [lx/ n_runs for lx, ly in data_x]

print (data3)
```

In line 35 the error appears. What I'm looking to achieve is to get a probability distribution.
How can I make this work?

Comment: I think you meant `data3 = [ly / n_runs for ly in data_y]` and `data4 = [lx / n_runs for lx in data_x]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "+=" to add float to a list. please use .append() instead

```
data_x.append([v[0]])
data_y.append([v[1]])
```